# How to compare numbers in different Excel spreadsheets?

Tags: excel

Dear stackoverflow members,

the background of the question is an accounting problem.

I have two Excel spreadsheet. In each spreadsheet there is the account number in column 1 and the amount of money in column 4 (sheet 1) or 10 (sheet2). Now I want to compare if in both sheets the amount of money for each account is the same.

I think it is an easy problem, but right now I cannot really think of a solution, because I have not worked so much with Excel yet. The total number of accounts in both sheets do not have to be exactly the same. As an easier explanation I added a screenshot![image: [screenshot]]

Thank you in advance for help! :)

Comment: *"The account numbers in both sheets do not have to be exactly the same."* If the account numbers in one sheet are not the same as in the other, then how do you know which account on one sheet corresponds to the same account on the other sheet?

Comment: Excuse me, this was not very precise. I meant that the total amount of accounts in both spreadsheets do not have to be the same. For example one spreadsheet contains the accounts 1,2,3,4,5,6 while the other one only contains 1,3,4,5. I know want to know if both values are the same. So the function should look for 1, in spreadsheet one and two and tell me if the values in both are identic.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to campare to rows in Excel you should use lookup function..
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324986